# Inno Setup - How to Install Windows Update Offline Installer

Tags: inno-setup, windows-update

I'm writing a function that will install a required component for my appliance, which is built upon PowerShell.  If a specific version of PowerShell is not found, I want the installer to help the user install it.  The problem I'm running into is how to appropriately call the offline installer for installation.  Here is the code I have, which is a generic function (I am using the [InnoSetup Dependency Installer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup)):

```pascal
function SmartExec(product : TProduct; var resultcode : Integer): boolean;
begin
    if (LowerCase(Copy(product.File, Length(product.File) - 2, 3)) = 'exe') then begin
        Result := Exec(product.File, product.Parameters, '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, resultcode);
    end else begin
        Result := ShellExec('', product.File, product.Parameters, '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, resultcode);
    end;
end;
```

I have tried using the following:

```pascal
function SmartExec(product : TProduct; var resultcode : Integer): boolean;
begin
    if (LowerCase(Copy(product.File, Length(product.File) - 2, 3)) = 'exe') then begin
        Result := Exec(product.File, product.Parameters, '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, resultcode);
  end else if (LowerCase(Copy(product.File, Length(product.File) - 2, 3)) = 'msu') then begin
        Result := ShellExec('', 'wusa.exe ' + product.File, product.Parameters, '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, resultcode);
    end else begin
        Result := ShellExec('', product.File, product.Parameters, '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, resultcode);
    end;
end;
```

When I compile and test the installer, I'm greeted with:

[image]

I am passing `/quiet /norestart` as parameters to the MSU file, which execute perfectly from a command prompt.

The installation file is downloaded to `%tmp%` for the current user, and I see the file.

Any help or comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.msu` extension is associated with `wusa.exe`, so the existing branch `ShellExec('', product.File, ...)` should do the job. You should not need to add a specific `msu` branch.

---

*Anyway, the specific branch can help with the debugging, so it's worth trying.*

The second parameter of [`ShellExec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_shellexec) is a `FileName`, while you pass in `wusa.exe xxx.msu`, what is not a valid file name.

This should work:

```pascal
Result := ShellExec('', 'wusa.exe', product.File + ' ' + product.Parameters, ...);
```

Though using the `ShellExec` to run an executable is an overkill, use plain [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) instead:

```pascal
Result := Exec('wusa.exe', product.File + ' ' + product.Parameters, ...);
```

---

When the `Exec` returns `False`, the `ResultCode` is a Windows error code explaining why the execution failed. You are getting code 3, what is `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (*The system cannot find the path specified.*).

So it looks like the path you are using (`product.File`) is not valid.

Make sure you pass in a full path to the `.msu`, not just a filename.

Try logging the path before calling the `Exec` and check if the file exists. You can use:

```pascal
Log(Format('Path is [%s], Exists = %d', [product.File, Integer(FileExists(product.File))]));
```